# pgfplot — label, referencing and caption

Tags: pgfplots, captions, labels

I've the following pgfplot:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = Number of threads (\#),
            ylabel = Task completion time (seconds),
            xtick = {0, 4, 8, 12, 16},
            ytick = {0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000},
            % ymax = 6,
            % ymin = 0,
            x = 2.5cm/4,
            legend pos = north east]

        \addplot[smooth, thick, color = red, mark = *]
            plot coordinates {
                (1, 23849)
                (2, 11920)
                (3, 7955.8)
                (4, 5971.6)
                (5, 4786.2)
                (6, 3991.8)
                (7, 3440.4)
                (8, 3018.4)
                (9, 3656.2)
                (10, 3411.2)
                (11, 3299)
                (12, 3233)
                (13, 3165.8)
                (14, 3168.2)
                (15, 3099.4)
                (16, 3050.4)
            };
        \addlegendentry{CoinFlip --- \texttt{Running Time}} 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

I wish to add a label like: `\label{graph:running_time_1}` and then somehow refer to it like in images and tables.

Also, I would like to add captions for this.

I've been somehow unsuccessful in finding the right way of doing this. I don't wish to create images and then add captions or labels; I just want pgfplots to handle all of that.

Comment: You can put that code in `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}` and use `\caption` and `\label` as usual. You don't have to use an image and `\includegraphics` to use `figure`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. I did what you said. I added: `\label{graph:running_time_1}` just before \end{figure}. But somehow when I refer to it using: `\ref{graph:running_time_1}`, it shows nothing. And I'm running the typesetter with more than 2 runs.

Comment: Okay it works! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put that code in `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}` and use `\caption` and `\label` as usual. You don't have to use an image and `\includegraphics` to use `figure`

Comment: as I say here you can add the figure environment