# \input{} is putting the files at the end of the document instead of where I put them

Tags: floats, input, pdfpages

I have the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, caption, pgfplots, pdfpages, graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}
\input{File 1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}
\input{File 1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

File 1 is:

```
Some text

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}, compat=1.3}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Title},
    xlabel={X Label},
    ylabel={Y Label},
    xmin=-100, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=145,
    ytick={0,10,...,140},
    xtick={-100,-75,...,100},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend pos=outer north east,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (-100,1)(-75,1)(-50,1)(-25,1)(0,30)(25,60)(50,105)(75,10)(100,13)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

(In case it makes a difference, my actual file has more documents added to it than this, and the plots in File 1 and File 2 are different from each other and have many more `addplot`s; I made this just as a MWE. It still reproduced the same problem when compiled.)

When I compile the document, all the `\includepdf`s are in the correct order, but the plots in both of the LaTeX files in the `\input` both go to the bottom of the document, even though I didn't place any of them there. The text in the `\includepdf`s stay in the correct place, but are separated from the plots. I need them to be in the positions I placed them in the file. They don't need to be on new pages (they're plots made with `pgfplots`), and (from my research) that's why I used `\input` instead of `\include`.

I also tried putting a line between each line of code but that didn't change anything.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: `\input` just includes the input file at that point, it never moves. What is in the files you input? does it contain floats such as figures or tables?

Comment: a MWE needs to be something that shows the problem, we can not run this as we do not have any of the files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The files contain plots using `tikzpicture` and `\pgfplotsset`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How should I make in an MWE. Attach some files? I thought perhaps there was a problem with the way I wrote the code that could be pointed out; I guess that's not the case.

Comment: they will not move either. Please provide an example that we can debug, otherwise not really possible to help

Comment: make an example (you can use `example-image.pdf` for the pdfs as it is available for tests, and provide the input files that do not appear where you expect in a separate code block in teh question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a full MWE; I hope it's clear now.

Comment: well there you go, as I guessed in the first comment. you have a `figure` environment. This is unrelated to `\input` you would get the same if you copied the code directly to the main document. The only function of `figure` is to specify that its content may be moved.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great coincidence, I got the suggestion to add the `figure` from [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101383/220092) to get the caption to work. So if I remove it I won't be able to have the caption.

Comment: documents have captions so that you can reference the moved insert but the link I give shows how you can get captions with non floats if you want that.

Comment: that said you can use `\clearpage` after each `\input` and the figure will not float past the clearpage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Using `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` as suggested by the linked answer worked, thanks so much for the help. Feel free to write it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: glad you got it working, I'll close as dup.